# Continuous variables and proportionality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have another problem in a statistics past paper that goes as follows:

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable, taking values in the range $[0,1]$ with pdf given up to proportionality by $f(x) \sim x^4$, $0 \le x \le 1$. What is the value of $E(X)$?

Normally $E(X)$ should be 
$$\int_0^1 xf(x) ~dx,$$
right? In which case $E(X)$ would be $1/6$. But for some reason that's not the answer in the marking scheme. Does the keyword "proportionality" have anything to do with it? If so, what?

Comment: In case the $f$ is not known to be normalized $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{\int_0^1 x f(x) dx}{\int_0^1 f(x) dx}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin as follows. the density is of the form $x\mapsto cx^4$. It must integrate to 1, so
$$1 = \int_0^1 cx^4\,dx = {c\over 5}.$$
We conclude that $c = 5,$ so the density is 
$$f(x) = 5x^4 \qquad 0\le x\le 1.$$
Now you can compute the expectation.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot I could do the integral = 1 bit.